# Is there a way to directly assign roles to a columns of a task when importing data?

Tags: mlr3

I like to import a data frame as a "task". Some of the columns are dates (of data type "yearmon") and I like to import them with the role "name" or "order".

Unfortunately, it seems I have to first import the whole matrix and can only change roles after importing. But this import is not possible, as the format "yearmon" does not qualify as a "feature".

How can I get around this?

Comment: Regardomg the yearmon column. You should be able to convert it to numeric and use it as such. Eg. June 2020 is just `2020.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only set the column roles after you have created a `Task` object.

The `.$col_roles()` is a method which can only be called after constructing the object in the first place.

Also note that you do not "import a data.frame as a task" but you create an object of class `Task` by providing a `data.frame` as an argument.
You should be able to supply any valid `data.frame` when creating a `Task`.